# PHP Refusing to Work with Postgresql and MAMP

Tags: php, postgresql, mamp, host

I am attempting to transfer data from my Posgtresql database onto a locally hosted website through MAMP.

My coding is simple enough, as follows;

```
<html>

  <head>
   <title>Test</title>
  </head>
<p>Stuff</p>
 <?php
   $host        = "host = 127.0.0.1";
   $port        = "port = 5432";
   $dbname      = "dbname = HappyTravels";
   $credentials = "user = postgres password=[password_redacted]";

   $db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  );
   if(!$db) {
      echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
?>
```

However, when I host this page onto my MAMP, the only thing that shows is the 
"Stuff" text, with anything to do with php completely invisible.

Am I missing something here? 
I apologise for my lack of PHP knowledge in advance,
Thanks!

Comment: Try [enabling error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: I've changed a 
<?php
echo ini_get('display_errors');

if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

echo ini_get('display_errors');
?> and to no avail, ive also set display_errors to On